# document says no way but is there a workaround to control editable in row/cell of datatable? #lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm developing a datatable in LWC, the inline function is needed, but I am asked to control some of the rows **uneditable**.

for example, we all know that a row in the datatable means a record. In my case, when a record's fields A__c is false, then this row should be uneditable.

**What I tried:**

Basically I haven't found any solution, I know I can control a **column**'s editability, but in row/cell? No way, I also tried to control it in onsave function to avoid some rows' save event.

But here's my client's words:
'Why do you allow me to edit when the row is not allowed to be edited at the first place?' Well, they got me, it should not be like this.

So, any solution? Thank y'all.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to write your own component. Unfortunately, some features just aren't possible in the built-in components, so you need to write your own. There's no real alternative at this time.

Comment: fox thank you for your advice, looks like it's the only way.